# Auto launch windows app from webpage, giving dialogue

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, deep-linking

I have developed a windows phone application using phonegap. Also I have implemented auto launch of app from uri. I am using using `location.href = "indiamartapp:///enq/"` in a webpage to open app.

It works perfectly. But if app is not installed on device it gives a dialogue box asking to search app on store. This dialogue is spoiling my user experience.

I want if app is not installed it should not show any dialogue. 
Content of dialogue is "Search for app in the store". Please suggest me some solution.

[image]

Comment: There is no solution. The app is not installed on the device, what should the device do and from where should it know what to do?

Comment: Please share your view on same